# How can I put first character small in UITextField in iphone?

Tags: iphone, uikeyboard

I want to insert an email address so the first character will be lower case, but when the keyboard comes up, the first character is capital. What should I do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set `autocapitalizationType` property of your text field to `UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone`

Answer (score 1):

You might want:

```
myTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
```